# Pytorch Scheduler: how to get decreasing LR epochs

Tags: pytorch, scheduler

I'm training a network in pytorch and using `ReduceLROnPlateau` as scheduler.
I set `verbose=True` in the parameteres and my scheduler prints something like:

> Epoch   159: reducing learning rate to 6.0000e-04.
>
> Epoch   169: reducing learning rate to 3.0000e-04.
>
> Epoch   178: reducing learning rate to 1.5000e-04.
>
> Epoch   187: reducing learning rate to 7.5000e-05.

I would like to get the epochs in some way, in order to obtain a list with all the epochs in which the scheduler reduced the learning rate.
Something like: `lr_decrease_epochs = ['159', '169', '178', '187']`

Which is the simplest way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the scheduler doesn't take track of this (at least I didn't see anything like this in the [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.html#ReduceLROnPlateau)), but you can just keep track of this in your training loop.

Whenever the learning rate changes (`scheduler.get_lr()`) you simply record the current epoch.